# Package doesn't exist in Netbeans, successful compilation in cmd, why?

Tags: java, netbeans, packaging, webcam-capture

I have a requirement to capture photos using system webcam. For this, I'm using `webcam capture library`. It contained three jar files. I wanted to package every thing including dependency jars in single `jar` application.

So, I sorted to unpack the dependent jar files place them in the `src` folder of netbeans project. 
So, I extracted them. Two of them start with the same package name `org`, so I extracted and merged them. Important third package starts with `com` package. I've placed these three directories in `src` folder of my `netbeans` project.

Now the problem is that `netbeans`, says that package doesn't exist. But, the same project **when compiled from `command line`** in windows. It **compiled and ran successfully**, everything was working fine.

But, when I added the problematic library as a jar to the project, it worked fine, only extracting and placing it in `src` folder causing the problem.

Why is this error occurring and why in `netbeans` only, how to resolve this problem?

My code:

```
package screen;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.*;     **//Error here**
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.log.*;  **// Error here**
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class Util extends TimerTask{
        private String filePath;
        private String type;
        private Timer timer;
        private Webcam webcam;
        public Util(String path,String type){
            this.timer=new Timer("Capture Timer");
            this.filePath=path;
            this.type=type;
            this.webcam=Webcam.getDefault();
        }
    public void capture() throws IOException{
           if(webcam!=null){
                webcam.open();
                BufferedImage image=webcam.getImage();
                Date date=new Date();
                ImageIO.write(image,type,new File(filePath+"_"+date.toString().replace(' ','_').replace(':','-')+"."+type.toLowerCase()));
                webcam.close();
           }
           else{
               webcam=Webcam.getDefault();
           }
    }
        public  void startCapturing(int period){
            this.timer.schedule(this,0,period);
        }
        public void stopCapturing(){
            timer.cancel();
        }
        public void run(){
                try{
                    capture();
                    System.out.println("Doing");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Util u=new Util("n082430_","PNG");
            u.startCapturing(60000);
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to supply the class path for all the 3rd party libraries that you source code relies on when you compile it

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm placing all library packages in src folder, I hope I need not give explicit path...and it compiles fine in command line javac. am I missing anything here?

Comment: Are these the source files of the libraries or the class files or the jar files?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the packages are extracted from jar files and packages contain class files...., when I place the `com` package inside another directory in the src directory, it's not showing error. but when jar file is created, it is showing....in order to avoid this, I needed to place two copies of `com` one inside a directory and one inside src....

Comment: That sounds really .... Weird. You shouldn't be mixing class files with your source files. The java compiler probably isn't using your source directly to look for class files. Instead, you should be specifying the jars as part of the class path for the javac

Comment: @MadProgrammer When I add classpath to folder containing the package it's working fine in `IDE`, but not when I generated jar file(showing ClasNotFoundException). The jar file contains the added library, but only when I manually edit jar file with winrar and put out the package from the enclosing directory of the package to my project package level does it work fine. (And I'm not just mixing class files, I'm just placing the dependent packages in src (it seems odd, but not working any other way)). When I compile with cmd, it's not showing errors problem with IDE only...

Comment: The IDE and command line work differently. I would surmise that the IDE has included the src directly as part of its class file look up. It's very weird to drop class files into a src package as some ides will will ignore them and physically excluded them from the build process (so it might compile, but won't run). You should be linking the external jar to your project, which will allow the IDE to add it to its internal class path when it builds and runs. From the command line, you should be including the jar file(s) win the compilers class path